# UWP and Binding to static class in different project

Tags: c#, binding, uwp

I have a static class in a common project where I have all my property with all my text (for example, all my titles)

I want to know how I can bind my TextBlock Text to this value.

I tried Text={x:Static...} but Static is not found.

Thanks

Comment: why don't you just try to set this static class as a context to your view and then bind to properties?

Comment: Because I have multi binding. And it's just to take the title of my page.

Comment: mayby I am missing something here, but what about creating property in your viewmodel that will return value from static class?

Comment: It's not my code, the creator created a public static class in Core project where I can found all my title page. And in my UWP Project, I want to use this title for my TextBlock

Answer (score 4, accepted):

{x:static...} is not present in UWP.

You can still do something similar, but the class itself must not be static. The properties in the class can be static but you need to create an instance of that class. So you will need to ask for a change in the core lib.

Then you declare that class as a resource and use that as the source of your Bindings. I recommend you declare the resource where it's globally available, like app.xaml.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <lib:Class1 x:Key="c1"/>
</Application.Resources>
...
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource c1}, Path=Text1}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You may set `Converter`with your static value return:

```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource GetStatiField}}"/>
```

Now according to your `DataContext` you should write your return logic:

```
public sealed class GetStatiField: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        //value is a type of your TextBlock.DataContext
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: With the latest builds of UWP you can actually x:Bind to statics which makes this a little moot going forward.

Comment: @JohnnyWestlake You can't x:Bind in DataTemplate.