# Bind Singleton in XAML (UWP)

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

i try to bind the Itemsource Property of an Listview to my Singelton StaticEntryList.Instance ... How can i make this work with UWP (x:static is not available there)

thanks :)

```
namespace SE_Projekt
{
    public class StaticEntryList:List<Entry> {

        private static StaticEntryList _Instance;
        public static StaticEntryList Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_Instance == null) {
                    _Instance = new EntryList();
                }
                return _Instance;
            }
        }

        private StaticEntryList()
        {

        }
        //...
    }
}
```

and here the MainPage.xaml

```
<ListView Name="StaticEntryListView" Grid.Column="0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StaticEntryTemplate}" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ??? :("> </ListView>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UWP and Binding to static class in different project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39978461/uwp-and-binding-to-static-class-in-different-project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to start the binding path with the class namespace:

```
<ListView Name="StaticEntryListView" 
Grid.Column="0" 
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StaticEntryTemplate}" 
ItemsSource="{x:Bind seproject:EntryList.Instance" />
```

Where `seproject` is the namespace tag declared in the `Page`/`UserControl` root element:

```
<Page
  x:Class="StaticBindign.MainPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:seproject="using:SE_Projekt"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d">
```

**This is working only if targeting (at least) Windows Anniversary update (build 14393) SDK**

Comment: then I get the error 'seproject was not found on the MainPaige'

thanks for helping me out

edit: Im already using sepoject: on another part of this Page and it works fine there

Comment: Invalid binding path 'local:StaticEntryList.Instance' : Property 'local:StaticEntryList' can't be found on type 'MainPage' SE-Projekt

Comment: You need to target at least the SDK 14393. I've updated the answer

Comment: this was the Problem 'You need to target at least the SDK 14393. I've updated the answer'

thanks alot